django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres.railway.internal"
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres.railway.internal" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

My Django project was working great until I changed the setting.py file to deploy it in Railway, using the variables Railway provides.
Since then, I can't runserv or migrate, that I get this error...
Here are the database settings changed to use the Railway variables:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'railway',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD_RAIL,
        'HOST': 'postgres.railway.internal',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


Error when I runserver or migrate:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres.railway.internal" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known


I'm not familiar with railway but the DATABASES credentials you supplied here, are they the same as the one you provisioned on railway?

Maybe the value for the key 'PASSWORD' should be str?

Go to settings and under public networking find an url like this
viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net:xxxx which is equivalent to host:port
Use the first part as your host and later number as your port number. It should work.

The problem was the Host and Port. I found public host and port on Railway. Now it works.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I faced the same problem, I solved by using public networking provided in the settings section of railway.app, when you click on the settings section you will see the public networking and below it is the host name and port number. Use that host name and change the port to that port number beside it.
